# How to understand which functions can be used in betterC mode?

Tags: d

I am trying to compile next code in `betterC` mode:

```
import core.stdc.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

extern(C):
int main()
{
    int [] x = [1,2,3,4,5];

    if(x.canFind(3))
        printf("Good");
    else
        printf("Bad");

 return 0;
}
```

On this code I am getting linker error. So it's seems that `canFind` can't be used here.

How to understand by function if it's suitable for `betterC` mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use -betterC, you need to learn how to read linker error messages. That code doesn't generate anything about canFind... it is actually the array literal that does it.

```
ppp.o: In function `main':
ppp.d:(.text.main[main]+0x8): undefined reference to `_D11TypeInfo_Ai6__initZ'
ppp.d:(.text.main[main]+0xe): undefined reference to `_d_arrayliteralTX'
```

Make the array `static` and it will work.

Well, why? betterC's rule is that it only works with things that do not require the D runtime library. It doesn't link it in (so any function that references the runtime functions will cause a linker error), generates C alternatives for some D features (notably assert in betterC uses the C lib version instead of the D lib version), and just doesn't generate other code that would need it (thus there's no TypeInfo and anything that tries to use it will cause a linker error).

The lack of druntime link explains why this is an error: non-static array literals are syntax sugar over a runtime library function (which happens to allocate it on the GC heap, so you can share slices of them without worrying about ownership). Hence, they cause a linker error in betterC.

Static arrays are simply memory in the exe's data segment, so no need for a runtime allocation and no need for memory ownership management (it is never freed). Hence, they work in betterC.

But, you ask, `canFind` comes from Phobos... which isn't linked in! So, why doesn't it produce an error? The answer is because it and everything it depends on (with the arguments you passed at least) are templates. Therefore, the compiler generates all the templates on demand and included it in your exe instead of referencing it from the library. Most of std.algorithm works that way... though, notably, not if you pass it string arguments! If you pass a string, it tries to decode the UTF data (big misfeature but beside the point today), which can 1) throw exceptions and 2) access various unicode library functions. So they will error nasty. You can work around that by casting to bytes.

So you can't depend on Phobos to work in betterC, but many of the heavily-templated algorithms will work because they are generated on demand and only use other templates or C-compatible built in features.